Overriding default redirection after successful authentication
I am encountering an unexpected behavior when attempting to implement a custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler for a one-time token authentication flow in a Spring application.
A POST request is sent to the URL http://localhost:8080/login/ott with the following parameters:

client-id: The client identifier
token: The one-time token
token-type: The type of token (e.g., REGISTER, PASSWORD_RESET)

A custom OneTimeTokenAuthenticationSuccessHandler is provided to handle successful authentication.
@Component
class OneTimeTokenAuthenticationSuccessHandler : AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    override fun onAuthenticationSuccess(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        authentication: Authentication
    ) {
        // getting email in authentication.name
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, request.getParameter("client-id"))
        val tokenType = when(request.getParameter("token-type")) {
            TokenType.REGISTER.name -> TokenType.REGISTER
            TokenType.PASSWORD_RESET.name -> TokenType.PASSWORD_RESET
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid token type")
        }
        request.getRequestDispatcher(tokenType.successRedirectionUrl).forward(request, response)
    }
}

Expected Behavior:
The OneTimeTokenAuthenticationSuccessHandler should set the Authorization header in the response and potentially perform redirections based on the token-type.
{
  "timestamp": "2024-12-30T19:00:02.104+00:00",
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "path": "/login/ott"
}

Actual Behavior:
The request results in a 404 Not Found response with the path set to /login/ott. Additionally, on further investigating i found out that the chain.doFilter(), in thefunction might be responsible for this behavior.
Question:
How can I modify the redirection behavior in OneTimeTokenAuthenticationSuccessHandler to avoid including the original request path (/login/ott) in the response? I am looking for a solution that avoids hardcoding a specific path and leverages Spring Security's functionalities
One solution:
override the overloaded onAuthenticationSuccess and remove the chain.doFilter() call and use OpenFeign to call the desired url. But my gut feeling says that this isn't a good approach.
Additional Context:
I have included a reference to the source code for further context: https://github.com/OmniCoder7/EVoteServer

You are doing a forward not a redirect.

why are you handing out jwt tokens directly to browsers as this is not recommended? why are you building this homemade security solution and not using the standard logins that are implemented in spring security.

@Toerktumlare it is not jwt token, it is one time token, generated randomly having no clue about user. And it's how Amazon(I have noticed about Amazon only) does it. It is the uri amazon sends on your email to verify your email. That uri contains the token parameter (although that token was longer than my uri)

@Toerktumlare it is not login implementation. It's verification of user's credentials like email, number etc. I am using spring's default ott (one time token) implementation.
